# Powerapps dropdown filter gallery sharepoint choice

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

How do I create a dropdown filter using a SharePoint choice list?

My dropdown isn't working in my Power Apps filter. I have a list in SharePoint with a choice field named `status` with the following options: "Awaiting Management Approval", "Rejected", and "Approved".

Within the Power Apps gallery, I want the gallery report to show all the information (title, name, etc) based on the status that is shown.

**Example:** I want show all the forms that have been approved and the information based off of this: Name of source in SharePoint = `vltest`.

**I tried the following:**

1. On the items of `Dropdown1` to set it to `choices(vltest.status)`
2. On the items of the gallery to set it to `Filter(vltest,Status.Value=Dropdown1.Selected.value)`

**Result:** This didn't work and I got red `x` boxes on every single item based on the gallery filter.

**I also tried the following:**

1. **Create a button**: On select:

   ```
   ClearCollect(
     FilteredCollection,
     Sort(
       Filter(vltest, Status.Value = Dropdown1.Selected.Value),
       /* ^ Dropdown1 represents the Dropdown control in your previous screen */
       "Status".Value, 
       Ascending
     )
   ),          

   Navigate(Screen2, ScreenTransition.Fade)
   ```
2. **`Dropdown1`**: `choices(vltest.status)` - Under screen 2, set the item to the gallery to *Filtered Collection*:

   [image: sharepoint list choice]

Comment: Your dropdown setup and gallery filter should filter the items correctly. Can you let us know what error the red x's are saying when you enter the filter? I would refresh the SharePoint list connection in PowerApp and make sure that the components in the gallery match.